# discord.py has_role via DM

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

im trying to use `has_role` but in DM but is not working.

```
@commands.check_any(commands.has_role(role_id))
@commands.dm_only()
```

```
elif isinstance(error, commands.CheckAnyFailure):
        await ctx.send("`ERROR: Permission denied`")
```

In server works!

In DM always return `ERROR: Permission denied`

Looks like can't read the role. Any idea?

Comment: how are you supposed to have a role in DMs? Roles are per-guild.

Comment: There is no anyway to do that check via dm?

Comment: There is, but it's not easy. A user can be in multiple guilds, and in each guild the user has different roles.

Comment: i understand, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: There isn't a decorator sadly for this (however you can make one), you should get the roles of the user in a specific guild, and check if it has the role you want. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A user can have different roles per guild, in DMs it has none. You should check the roles of the user in a specific guild:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def whatever(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
    member = guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)
    role_id = 123123123

    if any(role.id == role_id for role in member.roles):
        # has necessary role
    else:
        await ctx.send("`ERROR: Permission denied`")
```